# C# and MongoDB Delete Records Using List Of ObjectId's

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need to delete some records from a collection in mongo db using official C# driver. My code is as follows.

```
public static void Remove(List<ObjectId> objectIds)
{
        ObjectMongoCollection.Remove(Query.In("NotificationId", new BsonArray(objectIds)), SafeMode.True);
}

public class Notification
{
    public static MongoCollection<Notification> ObjectMongoCollection = MongoHelper.GetMongoServer("MongoKelimeYarisi").GetDatabase("KelimeYarisi").GetCollection<Notification>("Notification");

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId NotificationId { get; set; }
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string OpponentName { get; set; }
    public string gameId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public NotificationStatus Status = NotificationStatus.New;
    public NotificationType Type = NotificationType.RoundSubmit;
    public bool IsPushed { get; set; }
```

It runs without an error but doesn't seem to work.  How can i delete records using a list of ObjectIds.

Also tried:

```
ObjectMongoCollection.Remove(Query.In("_id", new BsonArray(objectIds)), SafeMode.True);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce this. I wrote a test program as similar as possible to your code and it does in fact Remove the multiple records. Here's my test program:

http://pastie.org/4618039

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Meant to add: you do have use "_id" for the field name if using the untyped query builder. I added a commented line of code that shows how to create the same query using the typed query builder, which is usually the preferred way to go.

Answer (score 6):

I used a different approach to obtain a mongo query and that worked. I built a linq query and converted it to a mongo query.

```
    public static void Remove(List<ObjectId> objectIds)
    {
        var linqQuery = from n in ObjectMongoCollection.AsQueryable<Notification>() where n.NotificationId.In(objectIds) select n;
        var mongoQuery = ((MongoQueryable<Notification>)linqQuery).GetMongoQuery();       
        ObjectMongoCollection.Remove(mongoQuery);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a method called something like:

```
public void destroy() {
        ...
    }
```

In this method you will use the list of your ObjectIds and loop through them.

```
foreach(Enitity enitity in entities) {
    ...
}
```

Than you can use **MongoDB.Driver.Linq** to execute specific queries in your list:

```
var query = Query<Entity>.EQ(e => e.Attribute, entity.Value);
db.GetCollection<Entity>("Entity").Remove(query);
```

Where Value would be the object's value that you want. 
This will remove the elements from the db that contains specific value.

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Seems inefficient surely since you're looping without using the mongo driver to just query it?